# What kind of comments am I supposed to avoid?

Tags: bug, comments, meta

MSO is being really helpful these days. Whenever I want to comment on a post, it already tells me what the comment section is for. I appreciate that, being cared about.

But, you know, sometimes Meta could be a little more detailed in what it tells me.

---

[image: Comment area screenshot]

---

"Avoid comments like " ... Hmmm. I assume you're trying to list bad comments there, Meta?
 Well, I don't think that worked out all so well.

*In seriousness*, I guess someone just used the wrong quotation marks for that part and cut off the value.

Comment: Whoops. Just found that one.